# Concave Hull around Line Features

Tags: concave-hull, service-area, qgis-network-analysis

I am using QGIS 3.16.10.

I know that the Concave Hull tool is normally used with points, but I've used it successfully with line features before (k-nearest neighbor only).

I'm just trying to get polygons around this and about 20 other "network radii" in my map but it takes hours to process.

How can I speed this process up?

I've tried a few ways of generating the end points of each of these networks, so those could just be the input for the Concave Hull, but with no luck.

[image: i]

Comment: Update. After about 4 hours of processing, the error message contains many lines like this:

File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\KNearestConcaveHull.py", line 519, in concave_hull
return concave_hull(points_list, kk + 1)

Comment: hi. did u get to solved this problem doing concave hull (k-nearest neighbor) to multilines features?